# installing MySQL on a local development Mac Mini

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I see that I can install MySQL on my machine using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or the "standard" installer from [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Is there any difference between these two methods that will suggest me to use one instead of the other?

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew seems to be written for OSX, so presumably it takes OSX specialties into account.
OSX is based on BSD, so all user installed software should be in /usr/local as a base path.

Of course you can also achieve this with the MySQL installer but you'll probably have to correct paths manually.

Another option is the popular macports repository. 
http://www.macports.org/install.php

Again, macports will more likely install a software like intended by apple

Comment: well, I just installed both to check what's the difference. They both got installed in /usr/local/. I am definitely no expert but, after a simple `mysql>status command` I don't see many differences:
Homebrew
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.8 (i386) using readline 5.1`

from mysql.com website
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1`

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew and MacPorts are both package managers.  They will do all the sorts of things that apt-get does for you on linux.  They allow for easy updating etc.  Homebrew is better IMHO and yes, I have used both.  In general Homebrew uses the standard /usr/local whereas Macports creates a special /opt/local.  There are more detail at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32724/what-are-pros-and-cons-for-macports-fink-and-homebrew and http://earino.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/macports-x-homebrew-a-quick-story-14/.  With homebrew, every day or so you simply run `brew update` and then either `brew upgrade` to upgrade everything or `brew outdated` to find out what needs to be upgraded.  If there's an update for Mysql you would then `brew upgrade mysql`.

To install mysql for the first time you simply:
`brew install mysql` though first you might want to `brew options mysql` to see a list of install options.  Homebrew will then install any dependencies and then it will `make`, `make install` etc Mysql for you and create all the required symlinks.  Homebrew avoids using sudo, wherever possible, by design.  The only thing you might have to do is add a few /usr/local locations to your path.

A advantage to Homebrew, though possibly a bad idea with DBMSs, is that it can have multiple versions of the same program installed.  So for example, if you are developing in php, you can have multiple versions of php installed and switch between them by changing your apache settings, and Homebrew will maintain them all but they are not in an isolated environment (as they are with macports and, another alternative, fink).  Maintaining multiple versions without a package manager would be a lot of work.